# How to define and call child route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have problems creating child routes in main routing module.

```
{ path: 'vehicles/vehicles', component: VehiclesComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Vehicles' }, children: [{ path: 'statistic', component: StatisticVehicleComponent }] },
```

and I'm trying to redirect to it from code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/app/main/vehicles/vehicles/statistic']).then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
        });
```

but I'm always getting error that route doesn't exist.

What I'm doing wrong, should I register somewhere else the route or I'm calling this router in wrong way?

Comment: can share your routing.ts file or try once below code this.router.navigate(['/vehicles/vehicles']);

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here but you can navigate to your `vehichlescomponent` using `this.router.navigate([/vehicles/vehicles'])`

Comment: @jitender I'm trying to redirect to statistic child route of vehicle component

Comment: try `this.router.navigate(['/vehicles/vehicles/statistic'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your routes like this. Move your parent component to empty path of child route.

```
{ path: 'vehicles/vehicles', 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: VehiclesComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Vehicles' } }
      { path: 'statistic', component: StatisticVehicleComponent }
    ]
}
```

Refer [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration) for more info.

Comment: how to redirect to that route then? I changed router but it still says that can't match route with this.router.navigate['/vehicles/vehicles/statistic']

Comment: Remove the leading forward slash `/`. This should work: `this.router.navigate(['vehicles/vehicles/statistic']);`

Comment: @nikihil Thanks, this helped me, but I had to use /app/main/ in front, I'm using ASP.Zero boilerplate and they are adding some extension before, But this part for defining route helped me

Comment: You're welcome @freshbm. Nice to know. I'm glad it helped.